# import Muhku library

Tags: ios, calendar, linker-errors

I'm trying to use the `Muhku Calendar` in my project. When I import all the files and I want to run, 2 errors appear;

> 1: 
>       Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>         "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventStore", referenced from:
>             objc-class-ref in MAEventKitDataSource.o
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> 2: 
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, one might guess that you need to add the EventKit framework to your project. I can tell that because the docs tell me that `EKEventStore` is a class in the EventKit framework. In Xcode:

- select your target
- go to Build Phases
- click the disclosure triangle next to Link Binary with Libraries
- scroll to the bottom
- click the "+" button to add a new framework
- choose EventKit.framework from the list
- click the Add button